# Gnome-shell and extensions error

Tags: 11.10, gnome, extension

I install and enable some gnome-shell extensions. Then I restart computer and gnome-shell doesn't working. It display only desktop background. I wonder how to disable or delete this extensions in unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you login using unity and go to

```
/home/user/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

Or

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

And just delete the extension folder that is causing the problem